# JHipster : Is there a reference documentation for the .yo-rc.json file?

Tags: jhipster

Sometime at project creation we do not choose some options and later we want to use them.  I read it's possible if we edit the .yo-rc.json file and re-execute jhipster as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33183983/233495).

That is why I ask this question : Is there a reference documentation on which I can relate so I can feel I know what I'm doing ?

Right now I use to create another project with the option I want to add and the pick in the generated file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [annexes](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#annexes) section on the JHipster Domain Language page should help.